# Regex - validate IPv6 shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am able to validate IPv6 addresses using java with following regex:

`([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}([0-9a-fA-F]){0,4}`

But I need to do this in shell script to which I am new.

This regex doesn't seem to work in shell. Have tried some other combinations also but nothing helped.

```
#!/bin/bash
regex="([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}([0-9a-fA-F]){0,4}"
var="$1"

if [[ "$var" =~ "$regex" ]]
then
        echo "matches"
else
        echo "doesn't match!"
fi
```

It gives output **doesn't match!** for **2001:0Db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334**

How can I write this in shell script?

Comment: Same regex should work. Can you show your shell script code?

Comment: Have added script to question.

Comment: Remove quotes around regex variable: `[[ $var =~ $regex ]]`

Comment: Also you should anchor your regex: `regex='^([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}$'`

Comment: What is your `bash` version? The script in your last update works just fine

Comment: I modified it after comment from @anubhava.

Comment: And yes, it is working fine.

Comment: It works fine now after suggested edits though I will strongly recommend using anchors in regex. Otherwise it will print `matches` for input as: `2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334:foo:bar:baz`

Comment: May I suggest that you re-edit and leave the original error? Else the question does not make sense any more and readers with similar questions could get puzzled.

Comment: Sure thing!!!!!!

Comment: @anubhava please answer it and I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java regex shown in question would work in bash as well but make sure to not to use quoted regex variable. If the variable or string on the right hand side of `=~` operator is quoted, then it is treated as a string literal instead of regex.

I also recommend using anchors in regex. Otherwise it will print matches for invalid input as: `2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334:foo:bar:baz`.

Following script should work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

regex='^([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}$'
var="$1"

if [[ $var =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "matches"
else
    echo "doesn't match!"
fi
```

Comment: 1:1:1:1 is valid IP?

Comment: In the context of this problem, yes

Comment: Brilliant... works on multiple IPv6 patterns. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

`[[` and `=~` won't work with sh, and awk almost works everywhere.
Here is what I did

saved as `./check-ipv6.sh`, `chmod +x ./check-ipv6.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

regex='^([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}$'
echo -n "$1" | awk '$0 !~ /'"$regex"'/{print "not an ipv6=>"$0;exit 1}'
```

Or you prefer bash than sh

```
#!/bin/bash

regex='^([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}$'
awk '$0 !~ /'"$regex"'/{print "not an ipv6=>"$0;exit 1}' <<< "$1"
```

Test

```
~$ ./check-ipv6.sh 2001:0Db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334x
not an ipv6=>2001:0Db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334x
~$ echo $?
1

~$ ./check-ipv6.sh 2001:0Db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
~$ echo $?
0
```