# regex - validate IPV6 address

Tags: regex, shell

Regex is working fine with shell script as asked by me in different [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565521/regex-validate-ipv6-shell-script?noredirect=1#comment78090301_45565521) but when I use echo command as

```
 echo "2001:0Db8:85a3:0000:8a2e:0370:7334" | grep "^([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}([0-9a-fA-F]){0,4}$"
```

There is no output and `echo $?` returns **1**

Do regex not work with echo/grep?

Comment: Use: `echo "2001:0Db8:85a3:0000:8a2e:0370:7334" | grep -E "^([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}([0-9a-fA-F]){0,4}$"` for extended regex support in `grep`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an ERE POSIX syntax here. Use `-E` option to make `grep` use POSIX ERE.

Or, escape `(` and `)` and `{` and `}` to make the pattern compatible with POSIX BRE:

```
echo "2001:0Db8:85a3:0000:8a2e:0370:7334" | grep "^\([0-9a-fA-F]\{0,4\}:\)\{1,7\}[0-9a-fA-F]\{0,4\}$"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/tTvvfU)

Comment: `-r` in `grep` means recursive search. Only other option to support shown regex is `-P` (PCRE)

Comment: @anubhava I am sorry, I mixed up `sed` and `grep`.

Comment: Yes I also thought so :)

Comment: This doesn't work on solaris. Is there any other option I should add?

Comment: @Batty From what I remember, you may have issues with it. Solaris `grep` does not seem to support limiting quantifiers. I do not have access to a Solaris OS though. If you have issues, please let me know, and I will re-vamp the pattern.

Comment: Take the regex [from here](https://regex101.com/r/UVHCPM/1), just remove all line breaks so that is becomes a long string pattern. It should be the same regex, with all limiting quantifiers unrolled. [This is how it works](https://regex101.com/r/dZN5Mq/1).

Comment: I found  a previous [question about limiting quantifiers on SunOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822261/regex-failed-to-match-using-m-n-on-sunos/38833648#38833648). So, the only work around is to unroll these quantifiers. Note you may remove escaping ``\`` from `(` and `)` if you use `egrep`.

Comment: This is not a valid IPv6 address.